# Qt, Linux, check if a given user has sudo privileges

Tags: linux, qt, qt4, sudo, sudoers

I am running Fedora 17 KDE x64 and Qt 4.8.1.

In contrast with Ubuntu, Fedora doesn’t give the first created user sudo privileges and it doesn’t add the first created user to the `/etc/sudoers` file. Therefore when installing programs on Fedora 17 KDE (haven’t tested the Gnome and etc. spins) it requires `root` (not `sudo`) privileges. So, we have three levels of privileges (listed in descending order according to the level of privileges):

1) root
2) sudo
3) user

In Fedora 17 KDE if you have access to the `root` user account you can give `sudo` privileges to any other user you want simply by editing the `/etc/sudoers` file and adding the line:

```
user ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

… below the line:

```
root ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Replace `user` with the name of the account you wish to give sudo access to.

But not every user has access to the `root` user’s account. That’s why the `root` user could give super-user (`sudo`) privileges to some user accounts.

What I want to to is to check if the current user running the application is registered as super-user. If so I will make the `/usr/bin/kdesu` tool use the `/usr/bin/sudo` tool which asks for `sudo` password.

If the user is not super-user I leave `/usr/bin/kdesu` behave as it does by default – it uses the `/usr/bin/su` tool that requires `root` password.

Currently, I am using `getenv('USER')` (“USERNAME” on Windows but I need this functionality on Linux only) to get the current user. The current user’s name could be acquired by traversing `QProcess::systemEnvironment()` where HOSTNAME and USER variables are listed.

Parsing the `/etc/sudoers` file is not an option since opening the file requires `sudo` or `root` privileges.

Comment: man getuid() ? Not Qt specific. root is always UID zero.

Comment: But I don't want to know if the current user is the "root" user, I want to check if the current user has super-user privileges.

Comment: `sudo -l` lists sudo rights of current user. If you run it, user has to type in his password. You could use something like `expect` to check if user has already typed the password before and is currently in a "sudo time window".

Comment: @snies: I think the user should not enter his password for `sudo -l`. I have just checked it on an account with no privileges and the command did not ask for a password, but simply listed all allowed commands.

Comment: you're not listing all complications yet. Just to add a few: dependending on the config, you need to be in the "wheel" group to be allowed to use su to become root. However, getgid() could be your friend: if it lists root, you're ok, if it lists wheel, you might be ok, etc.

Comment: However, there's something else here - you are asking us to solve a small part of a puzzle that probably has been solved many times before. Please elaborate on what you want to accomplish - the route to your goal might be considerably different from the sub-solution you seem to be working on.

Answer (score 3):

```
   man sudo
   [...]
   -l[l] [command]
               If no command is specified, the -l (list)
               option will list the allowed (and forbidden)
               commands for the invoking user (or the user
               specified by the -U option) on the current
               host.  If a command is specified and is
               permitted by sudoers, the fully-qualified
               path to the command is displayed along with
               any command line arguments.  If command is
               specified but not allowed, sudo will exit
               with a status value of 1.  If the -l option
               is specified with an l argument (i.e. -ll),
               or if -l is specified multiple times, a
               longer list format is used.
```

**Update** You need a (pseudo)terminal in order to run `sudo`. Here's one way to do it:

```
#include <pty.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int status, master;
    pid_t respid, pid = forkpty (&master, 0, 0, 0);
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* we are child */
        argv[0] = "/usr/bin/sudo"; /* I know it's a sin... just for a demo */
        execve("/usr/bin/sudo", argv, 0);
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
        /* we are parent */
        respid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        fprintf (stderr, "sudo exited with status %d\n", 
                   WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf (stderr, "could not forkpty\n");
    }
}
```

Run this: `runsudo -l` and `runsudo -l /foo/bar/baz` for example.

Comment: `QProcess process;

QString superUserCommands;
process.start( "/usr/bin/sudo -l" );
while ( process.waitForReadyRead() )
{
    superUserCommands = QString::fromAscii( process.readAllStandardOutput().data() ).trimmed();
}
`
This way I should be able to get the sudo commands available for the current user. But the Application Output window in Qt Creator states:
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

This is probably because there is requiretty for my user account and I am executing a terminal command through a graphical application.

The QProcess returns code 1. system() returns 256.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry, forgot about the tty. If you don't have a tty you can create one in the same way xterm or sshd create them (via `posix_openpt(3)` and friends), or call a little utility function called `forkpty(3)` from `-lutil`. I have added a code example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below one-liner script.
It will list all the users who have sudo permissions and not:

```
for i in $(awk -F ':' '{print $1}' /etc/passwd ); do sudo -l -U $i ; done
```